# Google Apps Script – Get folder name from folder ID?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

let's say I know the folder ID

```
var folderId = '************ID************';
```

I would like to **get the name of the folder** with that `folderId`. I tried to use [`getName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getName()) and combine it with [this code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator) without success.

It sounds like a basic task, but I can't figure out the working code. Is it even possible? Any ideas?

Comment: Absolutely it is possible to obtain a reference to a file or folder using only its ID, and then call a method of that file/folder class to learn the objects name. You don't show any code, so we can't help you further, because we don't know what you did. The code to implement this is almost the same as the pseudo code that outlines the procedure, thanks to the names of the `DriveApp` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the Folder Iterator. You can call the folder directly:

```js
var folderId = "yourFolderIdString999"
var name = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).getName() // returns name string
```

You can also call the folder ID directly in the `name` variable rather than using an ID variable (unless you need it in other places).

Comment: Thank you very much, I've just figured out this solution too :-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the solution seems to be quite easy:

```
function folderName() {
  var folderId = '************ID************',
      folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  Logger.log('Folder name: ' + folder.getName());
};
```

I hope this will help noobs like me.